# Problem running rst2html from command line

Tags: macports, python

all. Long-time lurker, etc.

I use MacPorts to manage [my Python installation](http://johnlaudun.org/20120131-nltk-on-mac-os-x/), and it has worked flawlessly until ... until this moment. And I am completely flummoxed.

I am trying to teach myself ReStructured Text, and so, trusting in the power of MacPorts, I did the usual:

```
sudo port install py27-docutils
```

If I use `locate` to make sure `rst2html.py` is there, it is:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/rst2html.py
```

I cannot, as the documentation suggests, use rst2html.py at the command line:

```
% rst2html.py --version
-bash: rst2html.py: command not found
```

I have my `.bash_profile` set as per MacPorts' instructions:

```
# MacPorts 
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

# Python
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

And I have also used `python_select`, so that when you run `which python` you get:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

Here's what my path environment looks like:

```
% more /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/opt/local/Library
```

**All I want** to be able to do is to be able to type `rst2html.py`, or one of the allied standalone commands (e.g., rst2pdf.py) at the command line, wherever I am and have it run. I'm having the same command with `sphinx` -- e.g., `sphinx-quickstart` is not working for me -- and I'm hopeful that the solution to this problem will be the solution to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `port contents py27-docutils | grep rst2html`. It will tell you there's a `/opt/local/bin/rst2html-2.7.py` file, i.e. you can run `rst2html-2.7.py` on your command line.

The additional `-2.7` in this filename is necessary to avoid conflicts between the different `py*-docutils` packages for different versions of python, e.g. if you want both the 2.7 and the 3.4 version installed. Of course you can create a symlink so you can use `rst2html.py` as usual:

```
sudo ln -s rst2html-2.7.py /opt/local/bin/rst2html.py
```

Comment: The addition of of the `-2.7` works! Joy! Thank you. (I had previously added `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` to my `/etc/paths` but gotten no joy. Is there any chance that doing the latter helped make the former run or can I "undo" that change? I'm not given to pruning PATH for the sake of pruning, I'm just trying to learn what's necessary and what's not when it comes to this kind of thing: working within the BASH shell is something I need to get better at.

Comment: I'd upvote you, but AskDifferent won't accept my StackOverflow reputation: I ain't got enough cred here.

Comment: The `/etc/paths` change should have made it possible to run `rst2html`, too. You might have forgotten to log out and back in, or the change might be overwritten somewhere in your bash startup files, though. Also, `/etc/paths` only allows you to *append* new paths, never *prepend*, which isn't much of an issue in this case, but might be in others.

Comment: Definitely logged out and back in. (Didn't restart.) I checked my `.bash_profile`, but I don't see anything that would undo /etc/paths. I will try it both ways, when I get the chance. Thanks for providing me with a working solution.